# Can I put something between two unpacked list in print()?

Tags: python, list, iterable-unpacking

For example: I have a list filled with ints.
I need to print it from a template(*with '\n' between*) with only one print():

```
>*sorted(lst)
>*reversed(lst)
```

I can't use sep or f-string because of unpacking lists. I found a bruteforce method.

```
int_lst = [4, 5, 2, 1]
lst = sorted(int_lst)
print(" ".join(str(i) for i in lst) + "\n" + " ".join(str(j) for j in reversed(lst)))

>1 2 4 5
>5 4 2 1
```

Isn't there any way to make it prettier and shorter?

Comment: Why the unnecessary constraint on number of prints? Technically you could put a `"\n"` in between but you'd end up having extra spaces on both sides of it.

Comment: @deceze It tried this it is giving one position off in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

My code sorts a list of integers and prints the sorted list twice, once in ascending order and once in descending order, with a newline between them.

```py
int_lst = [4, 5, 2, 1]

sorted_lst = sorted(int_lst)
print('\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, sorted_lst)), ' '.join(map(str, reversed(sorted_lst)))]))
```

Comment: I don't think it's easier only because you use maps instead of generators and '\n'.join instead of '\n' between strings.